# Escaping " character prints both \ and " in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm attempting to print out a string which contains a " character, like so:

```
NSString *wrapAccessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WRAP access_token=\"%@",  securityToken];
```

Which should print out the static string, a quote character, and then the string contained in securityToken.  But instead, it prints out WRAP access_token=\".  Why is the escape character \ being printed?  It is being added to http headers, I'm using AFNetworking 2.0, and getting back error 400.  Full error:

ERROR: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x10c0aca70 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x10c0abc90 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}

Code here:

```
NSString *securityToken = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
NSString *wrapAccessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WRAP access_token=\"%@",  securityToken];
[request addValue:wrapAccessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSLog(@"request: %@ %@", request.description, request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

The NSLog prints out the following for authorization:  (token shortened, the extra slash is at the start)

```
Authorization = "WRAP access_token=\"http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=WwD3j3G0hn141agd";
```

Why is the \ being printed out?  Is the \ the cause of the 400 error, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the backslash you see from the `NSLog` statement is just the output of the log statement. The backslash is not actually in the string value.

Comment: It's escaping the quote in the output because it's a `key = "value"` pair from the list of headers, and in order to properly quote the value, it needs to escape any internal quotation of the string. This is just in the log output, and will not be present in the header sent to the server. The lack of a closing quote would probably mess up the server, though, unless this is some shorthand I'm unaware of

Comment: You're right, if NSLog just the wrapAcessToken, it doesn't have the \ in it.  Is that being added by the NSMutableURLRequest automatically escaping quotes when I log request.allHTTPHeaderFields?

Comment: Yes, you're logging an NSDictionary in this case, not a simple string. If you added more headers it may make the logging more obvious

Comment: If one of you wants to submit an answer with this, I'll accept it.  My networking code is still screwed up, but that's beyond the scope of this question :)

Comment: May be you need two quotes? `@"WRAP access_token=\"%@\""`

Comment: Also I don't think that URL can be used as access_token.